# How to remove the milliseconds from timestamps with sed?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

My input file is as follows:

```
12/13/2011,07:14:13.724,12/13/2011 07:14:13.724,231.56.3.245,LasVegas,US
```

I wish to get the following:

```
12/13/2011,07:14:13,12/13/2011 07:14:13,231.56.3.245,LasVegas,US
```

I tried this, but with no success:

```
sed "s/[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\(\.[0-9]{1,3}\)/\1/g" input_file.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)\.[0-9]\{3\}/\1/g' input_file.csv > output.csv
```

You were almost there.  In classic `sed`, you have to use backslashes in front of parentheses and braces to make them into metacharacters.  Some versions of `sed` may have a mechanism to invert operations, so that the braces and parentheses are metacharacters by default, but that's not reliable across platforms.

Also (strong recommendation): use single quotes around the sed command.  Otherwise, the shell gets a crack at interpreting those backslashes (and any `$` signs, etc) before `sed` sees it.  Usually, this confuses the coder (and especially the maintaining coder).  In fact, use single quotes around arguments to programs whenever you can.  Don't get paranoid about it - if you need to interpolate a variable, do so.  But single-quoting is generally easier to code, and ultimately easier to understand.

I chose to work on just one time unit; you were working on three.  Ultimately, given systematically formed input data, there is no difference in the result - but there is a (small) difference in the readability of the script.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This worked properly, but now wodering why my regex didn't do the trick ...

Comment: Precise answer, in depth explaination of my mistakes, big up ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's,\(:[0-9]\{2\}\).[0-9]\{3\},\1,g'
```

Also, try `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, your version of sed may support that.

Comment: I believe you have to escape the curly brackets (i.e. `\{`, `\}`), but otherwise looks good.

Comment: Because you captured what you wanted to remove :p (`\(\.[0-9]{1,3}\)`)

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the "regex capturing" part of the regex ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You were near but some characters are special in sed (in my version, at least): `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, but not `:`. So you need to escape them with a back-slash.

And `\1` takes expression between paretheses, it should be the first part until seconds, not the second one.

A modification of your version could be:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/\1/g" input_file.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/\....//;s/\....//' input_file.csv >output_file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `sed` solution has already been posted, here is an alternate `awk` solution:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat inputfile
12/13/2011,07:14:13.724,12/13/2011 07:14:13.724,231.56.3.245,LasVegas,US

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F"," -v ORS="," '
{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=1) 
if (i==2||i==3) {sub(/\..*/,"",$i);print $i} 
else print $i;printf $NF"\n"}' inputfile
12/13/2011,07:14:13,12/13/2011 07:14:13,231.56.3.245,LasVegas,US
```

**Explanation:**

1. Set the Field Separator to `,` and Output Record Separator to `,`.
2. Using a `for loop` we will loop over each fields.
3. Using an `if loop` we would do `substitution` to the fields when the `for loop` parses over second and third fields.
4. If the fields are not 2nd and 3rd then we just print out the fields.
5. Lastly since we have used the `for loop` for `<NF` we just print out `$NF` which is the last field. This won't cause a `,` to be printed after last field.